# Simple SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery always returning 1 even when it didn't update database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am maintaining a Windows service, recently updated/compiled in .Net 4.5, placed on Server 2012, and using the same SQL Server 2008 database it had been running on before the update.  We ran into a snag where it is updating the database using a simple SQL statement, which has apparently always worked before the update.  Now the update almost always works, but once in (maybe?) a thousand updates it "fools" us and ExecuteNonQuery returns a 1 indicating it updated the row, but really hasn't.

If you want to tell me what is wrong with the code, please go ahead.. What I'm really hoping for is a suggestion on a more "fool" proof way to handle the update.  Maybe it would be better to set the connection to use transactions? Maybe it would be far better to use a stored procedure, as well as perform transactions in the stored procedure? How much better/Why?

The code is pretty simple (too simple?):

```
try
{
    string sql = "UPDATE table SET barcode = '" + newBarcode + "' WHERE pk = '" + reportId + "'"; // no semicolon in the SQL
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection); // connection recently opened

    rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (rowsUpdated != 1)
    {
        connection.Close()
        throw new Exception("...");
    }
    else
    ...
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
... // general exceptions handled
finally
... // make sure connection is closed
```

I know it is possible (though very unlikely) that outside influences could be nullifying the field after the update.  If that is likely the ONLY possibility, please comment.

Comment: I would start to use a parameterized query. ASAP

Comment: done. It is more secure now.  Do you think this will this affect the outcome of the return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update that *updates the row to the same value* is still counted as an affected row.

Compare it with the following:

```
UPDATE table SET barcode = @x WHERE pk = @id AND barcode <> @x
```

The explicit guard will *skip* this row if the update were to "do nothing" and thus it will *not* be counted as a change if there is no need to make a change.

---

While one *should* use placeholders (and `using` statements) as applicable, neither of these will change the result of the update statement.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in other answer too, use parameterised queries as well use the `using` statement to initialize a connection so you don't have to take the responsibility of it closing it when you are done.

Also use and output parameter along with @@ROWCOUNT function to see if any rows has been updated.

Use the `RowsAffected` variable to do further processing.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection string here..."))
{
  string sqlcmd = "UPDATE table SET barcode = @newBarcode WHERE pk =  @reportId  SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;";

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RowCount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@newBarcode", newBarcode));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@reportId", reportId));

    rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int RowsAffected = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@RowCount"].Value);

   if (RowsAffected == 0)
    {
      throw new Exception("...");
     }
   else
    ......
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The return value of ExecuteNonQuery on an UPDATE query is the number of rows matched by the where clause of the update statement and not the number of rows actually updated.

You should use the connection string option 'use affected rows'. When set to true it will report changed rows instead of found rows.

Please refer to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44194